# Mysql Query for getting multiple id with repeating

Tags: mysql, laravel

It might be simple but I am unable to do it. Can I have query `select * from mytable where id in (2, 2,2,5, 11);` to display the result for the ids. I need to repeat the result according to the repeatation in the query.

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried so far

Comment: You appear to be confusing issues of data storage with those of data display. Display issues are best handled in a presentation layer/application level code (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: @dimlucas I have a requirement of selecting a product and giving input of the quantity. I need to display the all of those products so that I can custom edit the detail of those products separately.

Comment: @Strawberry If thats the case I will try from client side. I was only hoping to find short and efficient way to repeat the data that are requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want. Do you want to get the row with id=2 three times? If so it's best to do it outside SQL query like Strawberry said.

If you **have** to do it in SQL you could create a table of ids from your list using unions and join it to mytable. Something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT 2 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 11 AS id) AS j
INNER JOIN mytable t ON t.id = j.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with models you can use this syntax got get a collection of Objects with the id contained in the given array.

```
Model::findMany([2,2,2,5,11]);
```

**With query builder:**

```
DB::table('tblname')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
```

**With a raw query:**

```
DB::select('select * from tblname where id in ('.implode(',', [1,2,3]).')');
```

However why do you need duplicate ids? Clean duplicates in array.

```
$array = [1,1,1,2,3];
$array = array_unique($array);
```